# Получение списка cpu и процессов привязанных к ним

Tags: linux

Имеется сервер. На сервере установлен `Centos 7`. В рамках интерфейса имеется только `CLI`. Под ОС работают несколько дополнительно установленных модулей. Для каждого модуля в его конфигурационном файле установлена привязка к определенному ядру CPU.
Имеется ли возможность как-то собрать список оставшихся под систему ядер CPU, не перебирая конфигурационные файлы дополнительно установленных модулей? Может быть можно что-то найти в `/proc`?

Comment: в программе *linux* очень много всяких фич реализовано. вы бы хоть заикнулись, о чём именно идёт речь. про [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html) или ещё про какую-нибудь фичку?

Comment: Речь о том, что после того ,как в конфигурационном файле какой-либо программы была установлена привязка этой программы к определенному ядру `CPU`, то это ядро, по идее, должно быть зарезервированно через, например, affinity от системы для этой программы. Суть вопроса в том, что мне нужно получить список оставшихся ядер `CPU` и получить их загрузку. Желательно через `ps`, т.к. эта команда позволяет делать более корректный снапшот статистики в отличие от того же `top`

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

> lscpu

- посмотреть(если не известно) сколько CPU в системе (core)

> ps -o pid,psr,comm -C thunderbird

- thunderbird к примеру ваша программа - покажет какие CPU заняты

ну а дальше посчитать

> ps -o pid,psr,comm -C thunderbird  | wc -l

- количество занятых ядер и вычитаем из общего количества

При желании всё можно завернуть в одну команду или скрипт